# *BBDB* buffer always pops up

Tags: gnus, bbdb

No matter what I do, the *BBDB* buffer always pops up when I read an incoming mail message.

I've googled around and tried all tricks I saw. Nothing works.

This is my bbdb config:

```
(require 'bbdb)
(require 'bbdb-gnus)
(bbdb-initialize 'gnus 'message)
(add-hook 'gnus-startup-hook 'bbdb-insinuate-gnus) 
(add-hook 'gnus-startup-hook 'bbdb-insinuate-message) 
(add-hook 'message-setup-hook 'bbdb-mail-aliases) 
(bbdb-mua-auto-update-init 'message 'gnus) ;; use 'gnus for incoming messages too
(setq
 bbdb-popup-target-lines 1
 bbdb-use-pop-up nil
 bbdb-mua-auto-update-p 'query ;; or 'create to create without asking
 bbdb-message-all-addresses t
 bbdb-offer-save 1 ;; guardar sin preguntar
 bbdb-complete-name-allow-cycling t
 bbdb-complete-name-full-completion t
 bbdb-completion-type 'primary-or-name
 bbdb-completion-display-record nil)
(add-hook 'bbdb-change-hook 'bbdb-save)
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Setting:

```
(setq bbdb-mua-pop-up nil)
```

hides the *BBDB* buffer.